# GWT, ASP.NET, jQuery... can you clarify me?

Tags: asp.net, gwt

Does someone can help me to understand WHERE to collocate Gwt compared to (for exmaple): asp.net or jquery ?
Does it only a toolkit client side, server side or... ? 
I'd like the "final product" written with GWT but i'm an asp.net developer.. can i integrate asp.net with GWT ?

AS you can see.. i'm little confused about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the idea is that with Google Web Toolkit (GWT) you write in Java, but the output is JavaScript, therefore you would just need to include the JavaScript output in whatever project you are using in order to have the "deployed" version of your GWT code available.

I'm not sure why you'd use GWT with asp.net rather than crank some jQuery to sit alongside your asp.net pages. That's more of a subjective subject.

Comment: Maybe it's a lack of knowledge by me.. but GWT seems to be "more enterprise oriented".. grid, forms etc... seems to have a "desktop app" on the browser... !

Comment: More enterprise oriented than .NET? Without getting too subjective about languages vs languages, I'll just say that .NET is entirely enterprise oriented.

Answer (score 1):

Since GWT is able to retrieve JSON data, you are free to integrate it with ASP.NET web site. But GWT is all about Java, I can't see any reason for ASP.NET developer to use it.

In case if you want to utilize it's UI widgets, you can try jQuery-UI, ExtJS or Yahoo UI client-side libraries.

Check out [Morfik](http://www.morfik.com/downloads/categories/Sample%20Projects), it allows to build ajax apps with C#